# MongoDB Database Semaphores and Node.js Process.NextTick()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency

This may be a vary bad idea, or a possible solution that we have to a database concurrency problem.

We have a method that is called to do an update of a mongo record. We are seeing some concurrency problems - process A reads the record, process B reads the record, process A makes mods and saves the record, process makes B mods and saves the record. Because B reads after A, before A writes, it doesn't know about the changes A made, and we lose the data from A.

I'm wondering if we could not use a database semaphore, basically a field on the collection, that is a boolean. If we read the record at the start of the method, and the field is true, it's being edited. At that point, re-call the method using process.nexttick(), with the same data. Otherwise, set the semaphore, and carry on.

There would still be a bit of time between the read and the save, but it should be/could be faster than what we are doing now.

Be something like this. Any thoughts, anyone done anything like this? Will it even work?

```
function remove_source(service_id,session, next)
{
    var User = Mongoose.model("User");

    /* get the user, based on the session user id */
    User.findById(session.me,function(err,user_info)
    {
         if (user_info.semaphore === true)
         {
               process.nextTick(remove_source(service_id,session,next));
         }
         else
         {
               user_info.semaphore = true;
               user_info.save(function(err,user_new)
               {
                    if (err) next(err,user_new);
                    else continue_on(null,user_new);
               });
         }

         function continue_on(user_new)
         {
             etc.......
         }
```

Edit: New Code:

The function now looks as follows. I'm doing individual updates to the arrays. This of course means that I now have the possibility, if the transaction fails between the first and second transactions, of having data out of sync. I'm thinking that I could simply resave the user object that I retrieved on entry into the function, overwriting my changes. I don't know if Mongoose/Mongo will not do the save if I have not changed that object, will have to try and see. Any more thoughts?

```
 var User = Mongoose.model("User");

 /* get the user, based on the session user id */
 User.findById(session.me,function(err,user_info)
 {
      if (err)
      {
           next(err,user_info,null);
           return;
      }

      if (!user_info || user_info.length === 0)
      {
           next(_e("ACCOUNT_NOT_FOUND"),"user_id: " + session.me);
           return;
      }

      var source_service_info = _.where(user_info.credentials, {"source_service_id": service_id});
      var source_service = source_service_info.source_service;

      User.findByIdAndUpdate(session.me,{$pull: {"credentials": {"source_service_id": service_id}}},{},function(err,user_credential_removed)
      {
           if (err)
           {
                next(err,user_info,null);
                return;
           }

           User.findByIdAndUpdate(session.me,{$pull: {"criteria": {"source_service": source_service}}},{},function(err,user_criteria_removed)
           {
                if (err)
                {
                     next(err,user_info,null);
                     return;
                }

                else
                {
                     next(null,user_criteria_removed);
                }
           });
      });
 });
```

};

Comment: You might just want to add a version to your documents and conditionally update based on the version being unchanged since it was read. If it fails to update, you'll know that there was a modification since it last read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that it just shortens the time during which the data could be read by a second process, it doesn't eliminate the problem.

The solution to this would be to set your semaphore in the same action as the read.  I haven't used Mongoose, but in MongoDB you can use findAndModify to only return a User record if the semaphore is false, and if it is false, in one atomic operation, set the semaphore to true.

If you don't want to use findAndModify, you could first do an update that sets the semaphore true (or to some specific ID value so you know that it is YOUR semaphore) only if the semaphore is not set.  Then, if that process succeeds, you could do the find (perhaps passing your semaphore ID as a criterion in the find).  However, findAndModify, if it is available in Mongoose, would do that in one step.

A variation of that is described here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/ where you do a form of optimistic locking that checks that the old values are unchanged before changing them to the new values.

There is a variation on this that uses a separate table to simulate a two-phase commit: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Comment: That was my thought too, after I looked at it. This is not buying us much. It's our first big project with mongo. Trying to keep it as safe as possible to do multiple transactions seems to be the ugliest part of the design. I do like the way you have done this, it makes sense. I guess we'd have to test the result back from the find and modify. I'm pretty sure it's there in Mongoose.

Comment: I do like the simplicity of this. The one thing that still bothers me is that if something fails, the record is locked. Might be able to deal with that with a try/catch block, or just in the error checking below.

Comment: If transactional safety is critical, MongoDB will be some additional work.  As Kyle Banker says in Mongo In Action http://www.manning.com/banker2/, nobody is going to build a bank's back end in MongoDB.

Comment: I'm an old relational DBA, and that's the truth. We are working through the pros and cons of mongo now. The advantages of simple dev, and no RDBMS upgrades on app changes is extremely tempting. It's going to depend entirely on the app and what it needs. But right now, it's looking like Mongo first, unless the complexities of data say RDBMS.

Comment: I'm an old relational db & desktop guy too.  This is new magic, and our old ideas can hold us back.  I bet this is not an abstract transactional db discussion, but a syntax on updating subfield discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:  Upon interchange below, this seems to be a schema and updating issue.  Question may become something like:  I have some entries in an array, and the ordinal index to those entries relates to some other arrays as well.  How do I perform deletes without having mismatches?

Three off the top possibilities occur, depending on frequency in the real world vs QA test scenarios.

1. Consider adding a deleted flag but keeping the records in the same order. If someone toggles, reuse the same record, but fix however you want.
2. Use an associative array (JS object) for each element (not a feature from relational world.) If you need an order, add an array that lists the keys in order. Both have syntax to update without touching anything other that what has changed, and will not overwrite changes to different fields.
3. Use an associative array where the keys are numbers.  Actual deletion won't hurt retrieval.

   stuff = {}
   stuff[1] = {some:'details'}
   stuff[2] = {some:'details2'}

Was
1)  Are you making changes to the same field?  Make that into an array, and push changes, and pop the latest to read the current value.

2)  Are you changing different fields, but data is getting trounced?  Then there is better syntax to use for the updating.  you can update field by field.

```
$set: { 'fielda': 'valuea' }
```

won't lose edits on previous fields

3) change your schema

4) change the timing on the processes so they don't overlap.  Or so they do so in smaller subsets, that you can manage to prevent from overlapping.

I'd like to know, just out of interest, what multiple processes are needed to make updates on the same record?  I don't work with anything that looks like that.

Comment: The client is an ipad client, and it is sending down multiple changes at one tie. We have built the items the client owns into the user collection, as we are often changing both info about the user and the things they have created at the same time. The document has a number of subdocuments. It makes it a lot safer for  updates then splitting it up. In this case in particular, it's the credentials from various external services - they may decide to drop some on login. The client is sending them out concurrently rather than one after the other. We may send them as a single array.

Comment: The use case of dropping existing credentials need not have a cross-update conflict - they are distinct at some point in the user record.  It sounds like you are performing an update of that field too high in the tree.  Show us the update and it's a quick fix.

Comment: Hi, Jim, yes we are saving the entire user object. The credentials are in an array, and then the objects they are associated with are in another array. We are currently manipulating those arrays, then updating the user object, then resaving the entire user object. This might not be the best strategy overall, from what you're saying. However, because they are arrays, and we are deleting members, can I delete a single member in an array? We also like to compress the arrays when done, so that we have contiguous numbering, rather than leaving gaps. So, the numbering could change between saves.

Comment: So, to sum up, if we delete member 3, and then compress, and another transaction has already pulled the data, then the arrays no longer line up. The issue with the compression of the array is that node is not happy referring to a non-existent member, and we tend to like to use for loops to access them.

Comment: Had a look at the Mongoose docs, and they do have an update, which in theory allows the setting of one or more fields, but has some other unpleasant possible side effects. So, I'm assuming that doing the individual field update means that the rest of the document is not touched. Doing a save on the complete object, will resave everything, even if we have only changed the one field.

Comment: Two possibilities occur, depending on frequency in the real world vs QA test scenarios.  First, consider adding a deleted flag but keeping the records in the same order.  If someone toggles, reuse the same record, but fix however you want.  Two, use an associated array for each element (not a feature from relational world.)  If you need an order, add an array that lists the keys in order.  Both have syntax to update without touching anything other that what has changed, and will not overwrite changes to different fields.

Comment: Further testing, and my above solution didn't work  with the second update, as it's an array nested in an array. So, we are modifying the client. The client was sending out the updates simultaneously, so this problem would have existed with MySQL also. Learned a lot from this issue, and the exchange. Maybe I have been doing relationals DBMSes for too long, and they now seem simple. The design is relatively straight forward. Mongo, the up front design time is important.

Comment: So, I think your problem is solved, although you have questions about simulating transactions that may need their own new question.  If I have helped you, I appreciate this answer being marked or upvoted.